# Loading large files into memory with Python

Tags: python, optimization, memory, memory-management

I am encountering difficulties while working with large files and datasets, typically ranging from 1 to 2 GB or even larger. The main challenge I face is the process being killed due to running out of available RAM. I need to perform various operations on these files, such as iterating over the entire dataset, accessing and assigning values to large variables, and maintaining read access to the entire file throughout the process.

I am seeking advice on tools, techniques, and best practices that can help me effectively manage memory usage while still being able to perform these necessary functions. I want to ensure that I can process the entire dataset without running into memory limitations.

Some specific points I would like guidance on are:

1. Efficient Iteration: How can I efficiently iterate over a large file or dataset without loading the entire file into memory at once? Are there any libraries or methods that allow for streaming or partial loading of data?
2. Memory Optimization Techniques: Are there any specific techniques or strategies that can be employed to reduce memory consumption while working with large files? How can I optimize data structures and algorithms to minimize memory usage?
3. External Memory Processing: Are there any tools or approaches that facilitate processing large files by utilizing external memory or disk-based storage? How can I leverage these techniques to overcome the RAM limitations?
4. Compression and Chunking: Can file compression techniques be utilized effectively to reduce the memory footprint? How can I divide the large file into smaller, manageable chunks for processing?
5. Parallel Processing: Are there any opportunities for parallelizing the processing tasks to distribute the memory load across multiple cores or machines? How can I harness the power of parallel computing to optimize memory usage?

I would appreciate any suggestions, code examples, or recommended libraries that can assist in resolving these memory-related challenges. Thank you in advance for your valuable insights and expertise!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use [memory-mapped files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) so not to map a section of a virtual memory in a storage device. This enable you to operate on a use space of memory mapped that would not fit in RAM. Note that this is significantly slower than RAM though (there is no free lunch). You can use Numpy to do that quite transparently with [numpy.memmap](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html). Alternatively, there is [mmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mmap.html). For sake of performance, you can operate on chunks on read write them once from the memory-mapped section.