# python 2.7 how to manipulate big file data extraction

Tags: python, sorting, date, dictionary, grep

here is how looks my datafiles  (from directory)
all is a huge (mess) log file pit containing different datas

so I have to get from that some data

here how it looks if I concatenate a few data

```
2022-08-31 23:51:05,491; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;example_data;TYPE_DDD;RRRR_SSDDDD
2022-08-31 23:51:05,491; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;example_data;TYPE_III;FT_RECEPTION
2022-08-31 23:51:05,560; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae>;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; END TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:51:07,233; example_data;;;example_data;TYPE_DDD;CON_CheckMeshArea_Output
2022-08-31 23:51:07,233; example_data;;;example_data;TYPE_III;APP_REQload rate = 171.142578125 KB/s ;
2022-08-31 23:51:07,521; example_data;8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8;;;<Source: PPPPP-CON;CON_CheckMeshArea_Output>; ;<Destination:PPPPP-GGGMMMM-VVV-VVVVVV;CON_CheckMeshArea_Output>;;<7740db78-8
05ad9427ab7>; BEGIN UPLOAD TO DESTINATION
2022-08-31 23:51:07,523; example_data;8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8;;example_data;TYPE_DDD;CON_CheckMeshArea_Output
2022-08-31 23:50:51,990; example_data;cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed;;;<cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed>;;<Source: PPPPP-GGGMMMM-VVV-VVVVVV;CON_CheckMeshArea>; BEGIN TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:50:52,118; example_data;cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed;;;<Source: PPPPP-GGGMMMM-VVV-VVVVVV;CON_CheckMeshArea>; ;<Destination:PPPPP-CON;CON_CheckMeshArea>;;<f13b8416-1a13-4212-aac8-
BEGIN UPLOAD TO DESTINATION
2022-08-31 23:50:52,359; example_data;cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed;;Uploaded size = 1 KB ; Upload duration = 0.008 seconds ; Upload rate = 245.4833984375 KB/s ;
2022-08-31 23:50:52,359; example_data;cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed;;;<Source: PPPPP-GGGMMMM-VVV-VVVVVV;CON_CheckMeshArea>; ;<Destination:PPPPP-CON;CON_CheckMeshArea>;;<f13b8416-1a13-4212-aac8-
END UPLOAD TO DESTINATION
2022-08-31 23:50:52,377; example_data;cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed;;;<cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed>;;<Source: PPPPP-GGGMMMM-VVV-VVVVVV;CON_CheckMeshArea>; END TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:51:01,920; example_data;;;example_data;TYPE_DDD;RRRR_SSDDDD
2022-08-31 23:51:01,920; example_data;;;example_data;TYPE_III;APP_REQ
2022-08-31 23:51:01,965; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae>;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; BEGIN TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:51:01,966;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP input data;server=p-APPSRV-82.SOMEDOMAIN port=990 user=service-p-PPPPPlication-0015 binaryTransfer=true passiveMode=true bufferSiz
cit=true protocol=TLS
2022-08-31 23:51:02,341;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP;uploadFile;setBufferSize;reply code=226
2022-08-31 23:51:03,575; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;Downloaded size = 135895 KB ; Download duration = 1.045 seconds ; Download rate = 130043.72009569379 KB/s ;
2022-08-31 23:51:03,647; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; ;<Destination:PPPPP-GGGIP-MMMM;RRRR_SSDDDD>;;<7b19f9ba-203d-4479-96b2-cc6d664bffcd>; 
2022-08-31 23:51:02,341;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP;uploadFile;setBufferSize;reply string=226 Directory send OK.
2022-08-31 23:51:07,279; example_data;8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8;;;<8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8>;;<Source: PPPPP-CON;CON_CheckMeshArea_Output>; BEGIN TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:51:07,479; example_data;8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8;;Downloaded size = 0 KB ; Download duration = 0.004 seconds ; Down
```

from here I wanna extract for each Source/Destination couple the upload/download rate/size/duration & id's (the hexadecimal parts)  So I had in my idea to

- sort by ID
- sort each by date
- make a specific output file for each
- then read each file for correlation to
  date/source/destination/size/rate/duration

Si my idea was to run a loop to extract that from a regexp & made it readable as a csv
but I had memory errors

*(the host has only 4Go)*

I tryied many things like

like

```
 import os
import re
import string
import sys
import datetime

datalogpath = sys.argv[1]               #  get the path of log files to extract datas
startdatestamp = sys.argv[2]            #  get a chronologic start marker
enddatestamp = sys.argv[3]              #  get a chronologic start marker
outputfilename = sys.argv[4]            #  output file will be csv formated results
outputfilename2 = 'testsort.txt'        #  output file will be csv formated results
searchpattern = re.compile('linked to the consume|size|rate|type_|source|dest')    # regexp to filter from logs directory
err_occur = []                          # just to manage error on empty line while reading the logs files
t_fmt = '%Y-%M-%D %H:%m:%S,%f'          # timestamp format
line_array = []                         # line buffer

for filename in os.listdir(datalogpath):
        with open(os.path.join(datalogpath, filename)) as in_file:
                for line in in_file:
                        #found = searchpattern.match(line)
                        found = searchpattern.search(line)
                        if found :
                                # STEP2
                                line = line.replace('|', ' - ')
                                line = line.replace(' - ', ';')
                                line = line.replace(' : ', ';')
                                line = line.replace(' INFO ', ';')
                                line = line.replace(' DEBUG ', ';')
                                line = line.replace('>', '>;')
                                line = line.replace('<', ';<')
                                line_array += line # keep line
        # end open
sorted_line_array = sorted(line_array,key=lambda line: datetime.strptime(line_array.split(' ')[2], t_fmt))
```

It might be run by : `python script.py ../data/ 20220810 20220813 out.txt`

I guess a better method would be to
make it read/grep all of a date as a dictionary -> then sort it -> then write specific file for it ? if so how can I do that ?  (*I m more or less new to python ; an short Example would be appreciated*)

Currently I got "memory error" whatever I change my algo/method
The ideal result I would get is separated files for each ID within all sorted by date lines  matching the ID `(as very final result)`

so  expectation is to get separated files like :

```
7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae
cd0fea11-de93-482c-b745-4336688e13ed
8841c2be-ee3a-4508-9c50-f817e5c7dfc8
etc...
```

each containing
all matching lines about that ID sorted by date/time

so for example for the 7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae file it will be

```
2022-08-31 23:51:01,965; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae>;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; BEGIN TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
2022-08-31 23:51:01,966;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP input data;server=p-APPSRV-82.SOMEDOMAIN port=990 user=service-p-PPPPPlication-0015 binaryTransfer=true passiveMode=true bufferSiz
2022-08-31 23:51:02,341;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP;uploadFile;setBufferSize;reply code=226
2022-08-31 23:51:02,341;example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;CPAPP;uploadFile;setBufferSize;reply string=226 Directory send OK.
2022-08-31 23:51:03,575; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;Downloaded size = 135895 KB ; Download duration = 1.045 seconds ; Download rate = 130043.72009569379 KB/s ;
2022-08-31 23:51:03,647; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; ;<Destination:PPPPP-GGGIP-MMMM;RRRR_SSDDDD>;;<7b19f9ba-203d-4479-96b2-cc6d664bffcd>;
2022-08-31 23:51:05,491; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;example_data;TYPE_DDD;RRRR_SSDDDD
2022-08-31 23:51:05,491; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;example_data;TYPE_III;FT_RECEPTION
2022-08-31 23:51:05,560; example_data;7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae;;;<7d4e2260-bf7e-4d81-9cd3-be7e4decaaae>;;<Source: FFFFFFFF-GGGGGG-PPPPPlicationS;RRRR_SSDDDD>; END TRANSFER FROM SOURCE
```

currently here is what I got is looking like :

```
[workdir]$ python loganalysze.fpu.py 2022-08-10 2022-08-13 ../data_Z2/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loganalysze.fpu.py", line 34, in <module>
  found = searchpattern.search(line)
MemoryError
[workdir]$
```

Comment: What output did you get from this code? In what way does it differ from what you wanted?

Comment: You could read the file one line at a time and process each line separately, then unload the processed data by appending it to the output file. This is how we process logs containing gigabytes or terabytes of data. Yes it's slower, but it gets the job done.

Comment: I got a memory error very start of the script I guess it is wile it executes the found=

Comment: @francois Please show the actual exception/error

Comment: you could use `print()` to see which `line` makes problem. You may also `enumerate()` and display number of line which makes problem. You will see if problem is at the beginning or when it will load many lines.

Comment: @furas i already know it is data (number of line) that makes the memory error, I currently try to find a workaround using files but I got a "no space left" of course... :(

Comment: if you know number of lines which make problem then maybe split data to smaller files and run every file separatelly - and write filtered results to new file and later remove old data from memory and read new file and sort it. If you don't have enough RAM then you have to work with parts of data and use disk.

Comment: you may also try to use `memory-mapped files` - see answer for [optimization - Loading large files into memory with Python - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72020651/loading-large-files-into-memory-with-python)